Odoo 17 - How to override this calendar method?
I'd like to override the CalendarCustomRenderer's onEventRender method.
I've created a JS file, pointed to it with my manifest, and it definitely runs.
However, I get an error:

The following modules are needed by other modules but have not been
defined, they may not be present in the correct asset bundle.
web.CalendarCommonRenderer

My JS code:
odoo.define('pkcg_appointments_customizations.CustomCalendarCommonRenderer', ['web.CalendarCommonRenderer'], function (require) {
    'use strict';

    const CalendarCommonRenderer = require('web.CalendarCommonRenderer');

    CalendarCommonRenderer.include({
        onEventRender: function (event) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);

            console.log('TESTING TESTING TESTING');
        }
    });
});

Any ideas?
